# Go forth and ...

Tags: logical-deduction

[image]

Who had the greatest of all? Single word or numerical answer.

Comment: Since the currently highest voted answer seems to be wrong (even though it seems to fit perfectly!), can you please provide a hint to point us to the correct (as in, intended by you) direction?

Answer (score 39):

I think the answer is

> Robert Wadlow, who wore US size 37AA (UK 36) shoes. (For a single word answer, then I suppose just "Wadlow".)
>
>  Reference: http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-feet-ever

Reasoning:

> When you multiply the numbers on the calculators together the product is $3215.3045$. Turn that upside-down on a calculator display like those in the picture and it reads SHOE.SIZE.

Comment: Creative! But not the solution

Comment: Nice one. Also, "Wadlow" sounds like [wallow](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wallow), which appears to be what the calculators are doing in the water. Edit: Ah, damn, just seen OP's comment above mine.

Comment: @user45515 You mean ... that product is a complete coincidence ?!

Comment: Yep! I think that was actually a pretty amazing coincidence.

Comment: I did wonder whether there was more to it, mainly because I couldn't see the relevance of the water.

Comment: The water could have been an oblique reference to turning it over. If this *wasn't* the answer, I'd be shocked - it fits *perfectly* with literally everything we have.

Comment: The title is kind of [proving it too](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Go%20Forth%20and%20Multiply). Is this also a coincidence?

Comment: Maybe the cable or the trees have to do with it too; also, the water isn't just water, it constitutes a river, which might also be some sort of clue. Maybe the light blue (daytime) sky is a clue too!

Comment: The math may be right, but clearly the answer must be "[the Shoe Goblin](http://www.beaverandsteve.com/index.php?comic=208)". :-)

Comment: The OP left our community and nobody to challenge this answer. (could that all be a botched troll that turned out to be a real puzzle?)

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> `3.402823 × 10^38` ?

Because the picture shows

> **floating** calculators.

So the "greatest of all"

> is the largest single-precision floating-point number in the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is :

> 50238

Because:

> When read upside down on a calculator, this spells "Bezos", the man with the greatest fortune and the owner of Amazon (the Amazon river is pictured as far as I can tell). I believe the "Go Forth and..." quote is a red herring to imply multiplication. It could be read as "Go Forth and Prosper," which Bezos has done, no doubt. Although, I am suspicious that the "who *had*" question could imply a dead person...

Comment: But how does it explain the 4 calculators and the numbers displayed? Fine, 7.33 can be read as eel, and the Amazon river has electric eels, but what about the other numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately not the solution.

Answer (score -3):

> 2.83, its floating higher in the water than the rest

Comment: welcome to Puzzling SE. I've added a spoiler to your text to avoid revealing it inadvertently. Do take a look at the [tour page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour/) to familiarize yourself with the Puzzling community.

Comment: This is also not correct

Answer (score -4):

Turning the whole thing upside down makes the calculators' displays read:

> EEL EBZ IE S

No idea what that means. According to Google

> The largest shoe measures 18 ft 0.53 in x 6 ft 11.07 in and is 9 ft 6.17 high

and it has a

> Converse

logo on it.

Comment: Nope :) Interesting though